# Read CSV file and write back CSV File based on condition

Tags: java, csv

I'm new to java. I'm required to read The input data(csv)(large number of records) I receive in the given below format:

```
A,1
A,2
B,3
B,4
C,5
C,6
A,7
A,8
B,9
B,10 ...
```

I'm using PrintWriter to write the data into the new CSV file. Is there a.ny way I can write into the new csv file this way from the above data? Here the condition is based on values A, B,C.

```
A,B,C
1,3,5
2,4,6
7,9
8,10...
```

Comment: Are the columns always A,B, and C?

Comment: Is there a missing comma after 9 and 10. Probably it is not a standard csv mentioned in rfc4180 "Each line should contain the same of fields throughout the file"

Comment: @dramzy the column names are A,B,C

Comment: @KelvinNg There are no missing commas. it's just that the data input ended

Comment: Are the missing values throughout the document or only at the end?

Comment: The columns are always A,B,C but the input may be large, as in, it can be a cyclic. It can read thousands of records for each a, B and C

Comment: In your sample output, `A,B C` would create two columns, the first with the label "A" and the second with the label "B C".  I think your input and output samples still aren't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is possible if there are always A,B and C. But this idea can be extended to finite number of constants

What you can do is something like...

```
public void computeNewCSV() {
    List<Integer> a = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> b = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> c = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input_file");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       String split[] = line.split(","); 
       if(split[0].equals("A") {
           a.add(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
       } else if (split[0].equals("B") {
           b.add(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
       } else if (split[0].equals("C") {
           c.add(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
       }
    }
    br.close();
    fis.close();

    //Now you have the complete information to be put into the new file.

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("output-file-name", "UTF-8");
    writer.println("A,B,C");
    while(!(a.isEmpty && b.isEmpty() && c.isEmpty())) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        if(!a.isEmpty()) {
            sb.append(a.remove(0)); 
        } 
        sb.append(",");     
        if(!b.isEmpty()) {
            sb.append(b.remove(0)); 
        } 
        sb.append(",");
        if(!c.isEmpty()) {
            sb.append(c.remove(0)); 
        } 
        writer.println(sb.toString());
    }

    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: The idea can be extended to an infinite number of arbitrary labels, not just "A", "B", and "C".  Think in terms of a `Map<String, List<String>>`